# How to display text where user clicks on mapped coordinates?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display text on the mapped location of my image after user clicks I have tried the `onclick` function but can't figure out the logic over here...

Here is my `html` code:

```
<img src="np-flag.png" usemap="#image-map">
<div>
  <map name="image-map">
    <area target="_blank" alt="Moon"  coords="352,220,93" shape="circle" onclick="myfunction()" ><p id="moon"></p>
    <!-- <area target="_blank" alt="Sun" title="Sun"  coords="374,534,87" shape="circle" onclick="myfunction()" id="13"> -->
  </map>
</div>
```

So far this is my JS but its just displays text in another div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myfunction() {
    document.getElementById("moon").innerHTML = "Moon";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve your question is bit unclear? What type of text you want to display? Is it from any field or element?

Comment: @ZainZafar I want to display the value like "moon" of the function after user click on the define coordinate with that function

Answer (score 0):

im not sure if this is the possible way for you question,
but check it out

online version : https://codepen.io/Orchanious/pen/XWmGQLq

css :

```
        .image {
        opacity: 1;
        display: block;
        width: 80%;
        height: auto;
        transition: .5s ease;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
    }

    .middle {
        transition: .5s ease;
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        text-align: center;
    }

    .container {
        position: relative;
        width: 50%;
    }

    .container:active .image {
        opacity: 0.3;
    }

    .container:active .middle {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    .text {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
        font-size: 16px;
        padding: 16px 32px;
    }
```

html +js :

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="image" src="np-flag.png" usemap="#image-map">
    <map name="image-map">
        <area id="moon" target="_blank" alt="Moon" coords="280,340,180,200" shape="circle" onclick="myfunction()">
    </map>
    <div class="middle">
        <div id="demo" class="text">
        </div>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myfunction() {
            let moonData = document.getElementById("demo")
            moonData.innerHTML = "Moon"
        }
// a way to check mouse cords
        // function showCoords(event) {
        //     const x = event.clientX;
        //     const y = event.clientY;
        //     const coor = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;
        //     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = coor;
        //     console.log(coor)
        // }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think you want according to the explaination in your comment, let me know if that works

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function myFunc(el) {
                var element = document.getElementById(el);
                console.log(element);
                alert(element.getAttribute("coords"));
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Image Maps</h2>
        <p>Click on the computer, the phone, or the cup of coffee to go to a new page and read more about the topic:</p>
        <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/workplace.jpg" alt="Workplace" usemap="#workmap" width="400" height="379" />
        <map name="workmap">
            <area shape="rect" coords="34,44,270,350" alt="Computer" id="computer" onclick="myFunc('computer')" href="javascript:void(0)" />
            <area shape="rect" coords="290,172,333,250" alt="Phone" id="phone" onclick="myFunc('phone')" href="javascript:void(0)" />
            <area shape="circle" coords="337,300,44" alt="Cup of coffee" id="coffee" onclick="myFunc('coffee')" href="javascript:void(0)" />
        </map>
    </body>
</html>
```